# Replacing the default Kernel in Ubuntu 15.10 with kernel 3.19.0-25

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I am having problems getting Ubuntu to work on my ASUS ROG G20 with any kernel greater than 3.19.0-25.

See thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/714454/asus-rog-g20aj-running-ubuntu

My question is this -

Is there a way to edit the ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso file in such a way where I could remove the default kernel included in the ISO and replace with kernel 3.19.0-25, then repackage the file? This would allow me to get 15.10 installed. Once installed, I would lock the kernel packages using synaptic to prevent kernel upgrade.

Being fairly new to Linux, I am not sure if this possible or how to go about it.

Thanks for the Help!

James

Comment: That's definitely possible, but will likely result in many problems, since many other system components have both hard and soft dependencies on a minimal kernel version, which is 4.2 for Ubuntu 15.10. Hence, why I'm voting to close this question as too broad. You will likely be better off with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, which currently features kernel v3.19.

Comment: Hey David - thanks so much for taking the time to answer, very much appreciated.  Gives me the information I was looking for.